# ReferenceError: is not defined : localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i am really confused right now, not sure if I'm being stupid or not but.. when my page loads I want to bind some localStorage to a variable called JsonData.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var JsonData = localStorage.getItem(0);

    .....
```

Here is a screen shot of my console to prove localStorage.getItem(0) has a item on page load.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I wouldn't of throught so.. because i'm setting the verible at the start of my code, all i want to do is call it by the console.log(JsonData) in chrome console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the variable `JsonData` is defined in a dom ready callback, making it local to that method - you are trying to access the variable from the `console` where the variable does not exists.

If you really want to access the variable across multiple independent scopes then declare it as a global variable, but I would recommend against it(simple doesn't like to pollute the global scope with my variables)

```
var JsonData = localStorage.getItem(0);

$(document).ready(function () {

});
```

since the data has nothing to do with the dom structure you can move out of the dom ready handler

Comment: How would I fix this?

Comment: @sabof sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I meant that getting this error doesn't mean there's anything wrong with his code.

Comment: @sabof yes, you are right... if OP is using the variable only inside the said dom ready handler it is fine...

Comment: @BrentFrench If you are only interested in checking the value of the variable use the console logging statement - have a look at the [debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) and [console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) blogs from google

Answer (score 2):

Unless the code is paused by a breakpoint in the same scope `JsonData` resides, `console.log` operates on the global scope. `JsonData` lives inside the `ready` callback and is not accessible from the global scope, thus the error.

I suggest placing a breakpoint somewhere inside the `ready` handler. Then you can use `console.log`. In Chrome, you can pop-out the console from anywhere in dev tools by pressing ESC.